# Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that for any $(b_n) \in l^1$, $(a_nb_n) \in l^1$. Show $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Question in title. So far I have no idea how to show it. I think that there might be a theorem in the textbook that makes it easy to prove, but I don't have the book on me right now so I can't know for sure. Here $l^1$ is the space of all absolutely summable real sequences, and $(a_n)$ is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $(a_n)$ is unbounded. Then for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists an index $n_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}|>k.$ Without loss of generality we may assume that $n_i\neq n_j$ whenever $i\neq j$. Then consider the following sequence
$$b_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{k^2},&\text{if }n=n_k\text{ for some }k\\
0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then clearly $(b_n)\in \ell^1$. However
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_nb_n|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{n_k}b_{n_k}|\geq\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}=\infty.$$
Which is a contradiction.

Comment: It's funny-- I finished writing down the exact same proof just before looking at this. +1